# Elasticsearch: More like this query on multiple index types

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, morelikethis

We have dataIndex with two types: users and jobs.

```
users: {
    tags: ['a', 'b'],
    locations: ['NY', 'SF']
    experience: [
        {
            title: 'Software Engineer',
            company: 'abc'
        }
    ]
}

Job: {
    tags: ['a', 'b'],
    location: 'NY',
    title: 'Software Enginner'
}
```

For a given user we are tying to suggest users and jobs using more_like_this query

User suggestion works fine using below query where id is the userid.

```
"more_like_this": {
    "fields": ["tags", "locations"],
    "docs": [
      {
        "_index": "dataIndex",
        "_type": "users",
        "_id": id
      }
    ],
}
```

For jobs we want to query against both jobs and users index. Basically match jobs same as user locations and tags. Is it possible with more_like_this query?

Comment: I will wait for answers before i make an answer myself but for now seems like if i have users and jobs in the same index and different types, i can use the same more_like_this query as i used for users. We need to make sure that both these types have the same fields.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @ali You can create multiple types within the same index and then you can search across multiple types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Just don't specify the type... e.g.

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
```